# Delete key values for NSUserDefaults in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

How to delete data from NSUserDefaults? There is quite a few answers how to do it in Objective C, but how about Swift?
So I tried this:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.removeObjectForKey("myKey")
```

Didn't work. Maybe what I really want to delete is not NSUserDefaults?
This is how I save data:

```
class MySavedData: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var image: String

    init(name: String, image: String) {
        self.image = image
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        image = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("image") as! String
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(image, forKey: "image")
    }
}

class ViewController: <...> {
    var myData = [MySavedData]() //Later myData gets modified and then function save() is called

    func save() {
        let savedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(myData)
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        defaults.setObject(savedData, forKey: "myKey")
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Just to clear some things - data that is being saved is small (not even close to 100kb)

And maybe I am saving data not to NSUserDefaults (I am new to programming), so here is how I get it (load):

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if let savedData = defaults.objectForKey("myData") as? NSData {
    myData = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(savedData) as! [UserLogin]
    }
```

Comment: `removeObjectForKey` is the correct method.  What do you mean by "it didn't work"?

Comment: Missing `synchronize`?

Comment: You need to synchronize to commit changes into NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Synchronize is [not generally useful](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-Foundation/): *"You should only need to call -synchronize if a separate application will be reading the default that you just set, or if a process that does not use AppKit is terminating."*

Comment: @Paulw11 By "it didn't work" my app is still gets stored value. Well at least `print(myData[0].image)` still prints value that was set before.

Comment: Is this after you have terminated the app and restarted it?  removing the value from defaults won't affect any existing in-memory instances

Comment: So, actually `removeObjectForKey` deletes value for key as expected. I made mistake by assigning "myKeys" key value to a variable and I was checking that variables value, not keys.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

removeObjectForKey is the right way to go.
This will remove the value for the selected key.  The following code sets a string value for a key in NSUserDefaults, prints it and then uses removeObjectForKey to remove and print the key value again.  After removeObjectForKey the value is nil.

```
let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var keyValue = prefs.stringForKey("TESTKEY")
print("Key Value not set \(keyValue)")
let strHello = "HELLO WORLD"

prefs.setObject(strHello, forKey: "TESTKEY")
keyValue = prefs.stringForKey("TESTKEY")
print("Key Value \(keyValue)")

prefs.removeObjectForKey("TESTKEY")
keyValue = prefs.stringForKey("TESTKEY")
print("Key Value after remove \(keyValue)")
```

Returns:

Key Value not set nil

Key Value Optional("HELLO WORLD")

Key Value after remove nil

### Update Swift 3:

```
let prefs = UserDefaults.standard
keyValue = prefs.string(forKey:"TESTKEY")
prefs.removeObject(forKey:"TESTKEY")
```

Comment: prefs.removeObjectForKey("TESTKEY") worked. Exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

The code you have written will work fine, but NSUserDefaults synchronise at certain time interval.

As you want that should reflect in NSUserDefaults immediately ,so u need to write **synchronise**

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.removeObjectForKey("myKey") 
defaults.synchronize()
```

Comment: What is the issue still now  ? check what is in defaults by keeping break point .

Comment: Oh, I think I got the mistake, I clear NSUserdafaults, but variable in ViewController (myData) still contains the value!

Answer (score 13):

Try This

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removePersistentDomainForName(NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier!)
```

for Swift 3

```
UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)
```

But this will clear all values from NSUserDefaults.careful while using.

Comment: I don't want to clear all values, only for key "myKey"

Answer (score 8):

Removing UserDefaults for key in swift 3, based upon the top answer, just slightly different syntax:

```
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "doesContractExist")
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. No need for multiple lines of code.

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4.x Remove all key in UserDefaults**

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let dictionary = defaults.dictionaryRepresentation()

    dictionary.keys.forEach 
    { key in   defaults.removeObject(forKey: key)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I would go for a solution which setting the *value* to `nil` for a *key*.

### Swift 3

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(nil, forKey: "key")
```

### Swift 2.x

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(nil, forKey: "key")
```

---

*NOTE: that is a clear and straight statement, but bear in mind there is a limit to store information in `NSUserDefaults`, it is definitely **not** the right place to store large binary files (like e.g. images) – for that there is a `Documents` folder. however it is not defined how big the `var image: String` which you encode/decode.*

Answer (score 3):

Use following for loop:

```
for key in NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation().keys {
   NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey(key.description)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To nuke all `UserDefaults` keys, you can use the following code in Swift 3.x:

```
UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)
```

Answer (score 1):

In **Swift 5.0, iOS 15** below single line of code is enough.

```
UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation().keys.forEach(defaults.removeObject(forKey:))
```

Or try this

```
if let appDomain = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier {
   UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: appDomain)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func  remove_pref(remove_key : String){
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: remove_key)
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}
```

Comment: According to Apples documentation " .synchronize() this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used."

Answer (score -1):

***Update code for Swift :*** 
**Used below line of code to Delete key values for NSUserDefaults in Swift**

```
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(nil, forKey: "YouEnterKey")
```